# Why I can not put and see a custom view in a layout?

Tags: android

Why I can not put and see a custom view in a layout?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    A a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a = (A) findViewById(R.id.a);
        setContentView(a);
    }

    class A extends View {
        Paint paint;

        A(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint = new Paint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawRect(10, 20, 60, 100, paint);
       }
    }
}
```

And please see the following image:

[image]

Comment: Try providing the other view constructors also.

Comment: Is this view a sub-class of the Activity class ?

Answer (score 1):

Override the below constructor on your view class and see if it works. When you include the view in xml you need to include the xml constructor in the view.

View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

```
 public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
```

Comment: thank you, if this is possible say for me that how can I use and override the `View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` in my class.

Answer (score 1):

View A is an inner class of the Activity class, so the defination in the layout file is a little different.

Use this pattern:

```
<view class="{package}.{ParentClass}${innerClass}" />
```

In your case:

```
<view class="com.example.tec.test.MainActivity$A" />
```

Notice it's lowercase "view" not "View". And the inner class A should be declared as "public static" like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Activity's methods

    public static class A extends View {
        public A(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        // A's methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using your help.Thank you. The following code is for other questioner.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <view class="com.example.tec.test.A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/a"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the following java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    A a;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    a= (A) findViewById(R.id.a);
        a = new A(this);
        setContentView(a);
    }

    }
 class A extends View {
    Paint paint;
    public A(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
     public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);

     }

     public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);

     }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(10, 20, 60, 70, paint);

    }
}
```